# What licenses should I get for the (flight) equipments that I want to make?

Tags: aircraft-systems, equipment

For making and selling all equipments of aircrafts what or which licenses should I get? and from where? Will I be able to sell them all around the world?

**Edit:** This question is different than this [one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82961/which-licenses-must-i-get-for-the-flight-equipments-of-aircrafts-that-i-want-t). One of them is for a new equipment and another is to modify them. It looks they need different licenses. Please vote to reopen it.

Comment: Please explain your research effort so far and clarify exactly which doubt you have

Comment: @expeditedescent I even don't know from which office or organization should I start. Which one is in charge!? Please vote to reopen the question. see the edition.

Comment: This question is WAY too broad.  ("All equipment... all around the world"?!)  What country are you in?  Start there, with whatever aviation authority exists, then expand.

Comment: Might I suggest researching Title 14 of the US Code of Federal Regulations. It would be a good start. It is a very long read and very general. But, your question is too broad to narrow an answer down any further. For more detail, edit your question to include country, aircraft category, class and type, product type, product use, etc.